# How to add spinner items with loooping results

Tags: loops, for-loop, spinner, android-spinner

I want spinner items are numbers 1 through 10 using looping for, i use this way, but the result of spinner items is only 10, while i want is 1 to 10, can you help me to solve this problem?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sptgl);

    for(int i=1 ;i <=10; i++){
        List<Integer> dttgl = new ArrayList<>();
        dttgl.add(i);
        ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,dttgl);
        dataadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp1.setAdapter(dataadapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Integer> dttgl = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=1 ;i <=10; i++){

        dttgl.add(i);
    }

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,dttgl);
        dataadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp1.setAdapter(dataadapter);
```